# Jupyter & Python: Why can't a child's call to a parent method recognize the parent's import?

Tags: python, inheritance, module, jupyter-notebook, nameerror

In my current working directory I have the files active.ipynb which contains class B, subclass of A, and I have A.py where A is defined.

When I'm defining everything within the notebook (i.e. class A and B are both defined within a cell in the notebook), everything works fine which is what I expect. When class A is moved into it's own file, I get problems. Importing math in class B does not help, and I also tested this in a separate notebook from my real project to make sure I'm not doing something detrimental somewhere.

Consider

A.py contents:

```
#edited to reflect this issue occurring regardless of import location

import math    

class A:

    def method(self):
        #parent related code...
        self.parentmethod()

    def parentmethod(self):
        print(math.pi)
```

In my current cell I have:

```
import A


class B(A.A):
    def method(self):
        #child related overridden code...
        self.parentmethod()

b = B()

b.method()
```

and I get the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-42c1e6969f03> in <module>
      9 b = B()
     10 
---> 11 b.method()

<ipython-input-84-42c1e6969f03> in method(self)
      5     def method(self):
      6         #child related code...
----> 7         self.parentmethod()
      8 
      9 b = B()

~\Documents\Projects\FunctionNetwork\A.py in parentmethod(self)
      7 
      8     def parentmethod(self):
----> 9         print(math.pi)

NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

What's going on?

Comment: `math` is **not defined** in your `A.py` module, so obviously `math` will thrown a name error. Importing into the class body will create a *class variable* `A.math`. Move the import out of the class definition

Comment: I appreciate the response, and this is an embarrassing mistake on my part. I get the idea of static methods and variables, but I didn't really think much about it with respect to an import statement. With that said, I actually started off with the import in the module's body, that's where I first got the error. Then I moved it into the init method (guessing I would need self.math?) and finally the class body. Yet today when I moved the import back into the module, it worked. Go figure.

Comment: imports that don't occur at the top of the module should be considered strange. Sometimes it's the best solution among many poor options, but generally, you should consider it a red-flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by accidentally repeating the error moments ago, and now I can replicate it at will.

I copied class A from JN, and accidentally missed the math import at the module level. I then imported class A into a fresh cell and called it's method which lead to a name error referencing the math module. This is expected because I didn't import math anywhere.

I added the math import to A.py, saved it, then reran the cell assuming it would reimport A.py with the new information. This is not the case. When I cleared the notebook, only then did it recognize that I updated A.py.

Apparently, being consistent can be a boon even if you're consistently sloppy.